# Create new JUnit test and run with git bisect

Tags: git, junit, git-bisect

If I get a bug report that says "Since this release I cannot longer enter negative values" then I would like to create a JUnit test for this.

```
@Test
assertCanPutNegative(){}
```

This testcase I would like to run on the latest 10 commits for example by doing

```
git bisect start
git bisect bad
git bisect good a4426026a056049504 <- commit known to work
```

then i would like to run my newly created testcase on all of these commits.

Can I do that easily with `git bisect run mvn clean test` (because my test will disappear in the bisecting process)?

Can i do something else in the run command to make this work?

Comment: You can store your test in a stash with pop it each time you do the bisect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

- create a new branch
- add the test with a new commit
- place the commit with rebase just after the last known working commit
- run `git bisect run mvn clean test`

Comment: You mean like G-T-3-4-5-6-7-B. Where G is good T is testcommit and B is bad?

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.